# Grouping common css rules based on condition in LESS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I'm looking for some refactoring assistance to group common button properties under one rule to reduce the amount of code for my CSS rules.

The logic basically says if "show-footer" is true then I display two buttons side-by-side. Otherwise, I display one button with 100% width. I want to try and group whatever base button properties under that first rule, but not sure how to clean this up.

Is there any way to abstract that logic out from the two custom elements and put them into that first LESS rule to make it seem less brittle?

#### LESS

```
  > .editor-properties > .editor-btn-group > button {
    display: none;
  }
}

@{customElementNamespace}search-settings.show-save {
  > .editor-properties > .editor-btn-group > .editor-save {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@{customElementNamespace}search-settings.save-cancel {
  > .editor-properties > .editor-btn-group > button {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="editor-btn-group">
  <button class="editor-cancel is-negative">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
      <span>
          Cancel
      </span>
  </button>
  <button class="editor-save is-positive">
       <span class="fa fa-floppy-o">
       </span>
      <span>
          Save
      </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
showSave: function() {
    this.$el.toggleClass('show-save', this.options.showSave === true);
},
showCancel: function() {
    this.$el.toggleClass('save-cancel', this.options.showFooter === true);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this with flex

You need `flex-grow: 1` on the buttons so they will grow to your container width when there is only 1 button and `justify-content: space-between` on the container so the buttons are on the edge of let and right

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-btn-group">
  <button class="editor-cancel is-negative">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
      <span>
          Cancel
      </span>
  </button>
  <button class="editor-save is-positive">
       <span class="fa fa-floppy-o">
       </span>
      <span>
          Save
      </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Now with only 1 button(pretend the other button is hidden), note the css is the same

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-btn-group">
  <button class="editor-cancel is-negative">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
      <span>
          Cancel
      </span>
  </button>
  
</div>
```

For displaying the buttons you just need

```
.show-save .editor-cancel,
.show-cancel .editor-save { 
    display: none;
}
```

The only way to reduce that anymore is that you create a class for display none and add/remove it via js.

Comment: I still need two buttons since they both have cancel and save, just on a conditional basis.

Comment: Yes I know I am just showing you how both cases looks, your js/html is not changing.

Comment: Gotcha. I still need to account for conditional visibility though. How does that work in this case?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean conditional visibility? You would show/hide the buttons the same way by setting display none to which button that needs it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Correct. So based on the conditionals in the javascript I need to alter the visibility of the buttons. So do I still need 2 css rules for each of those buttons?

Comment: If you add the class same way you are now then yes, you could also make a class with display none and just add it to whichever button needs, but then you also need to remove that class when you need to add it to the other one. My solution does not require you to set any width or display block, you just need to hide the button and you can write that in one line, like `.show-save .editor-group .cancel, .show-cancel .editor-group .save { display: none }` for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166266/discussion-between-ryan-hack-and-huangism).